# How do I get the value of a D-Bus property?

Tags: c, dbus

I'm trying to create a general remote control application for MPRIS based media players. Controlling the media players is so easy, but as I'm quite new to D-Bus and DBus-GLib, getting values from D-Bus is a bit screwed up for me.

From the documentations I see that I need to get the PlaybackStatus property if I want to know if my player is actually playing something, but I cannot find a working example for getting this value in C.

Currently the line to get it looks like this:

```
dbus_g_proxy_call(player_proxy, "Get", &err, G_TYPE_STRING, "Volume", G_TYPE_INVALID, G_TYPE_INT, &volume, G_TYPE_INVALID);
```

Certainly, it does not work, as the `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player` interface doesn't understand the Get method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Certainly, it does not work, as the `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player` interface doesn't understand the `Get` method.

This is the clue you need. The `Get` method is actually on the [`org.freedesktop.DBus.Properties` interface](https://dbus.freedesktop.org/doc/dbus-specification.html#standard-interfaces-properties), so you need to call it on a proxy object for that interface, rather than the `player_proxy` object (which is presumably a proxy for the `org.mpris.MediaPlayer2.Player` interface).

Answer (score 0):

After looking through [this source code](http://fossies.org/linux/misc/old/hxplay-11.0.0.tar.gz/player/common/gtk/hxdbusplayer.c), it seems you need to use `"IsPlaying"`, as seen in the method `hx_dbus_player_is_playing`.